# How to update all the values in a Dictionary<string, bool>

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I am using c# vs2005 compact framework.

I need to update all the values in the dictionary to false.

```
foreach (string key in parameterDictionary.Keys.ToList())
  parameterDictionary[key] = false;
```

**".ToList() is not available"** in  compactframework.
How can i loop and update.

Can any one suggest the way to update all the values in a dictionary.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't know if the compact framework is different, but you can't modify the dictionary KeyValuePair directly in a ForEach.  You have to copy a list of keys first:

```
List<string> keys = new List<string>(parameterDictionary.Keys);
foreach (string key in keys)
  parameterDictionary[key] = false;
```